# Remove pages from Pages

Tags: macos, pages

I have decided to turn my two page document in Pages to just one page. I cannot seem to delete the second page. It is the flyer template.

Comment: Thanks for asking and thanks even more for answering. Would you edit in if you are using Pages on an iPhone or a Mac or on the web? That might help others if the solution isn't universal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete everything on the second page, the second page should disappear. Maybe the template needs to be removed or there are spaces on page 2 that you don't see.

To avoid a lot of guesswork, the function "View -> Show invisibles" should make obvious what is on the page:

[image]

Invisible characters will then show on the page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

Highlight everything (even if nothing) on that page Usually this will show in blue including the invisibles.
Make sure you attempt to highlight everything by selecting the whole page.
Press Backspace/delete until all of that page is clear.
Continue until your cursor lands on your first page.
By then the offending second blank page should have gone.

Comment: I edited my answer. If this helped you, please mark it as answered! Also, I think your answer doesn't add more elements than mine did. Thanks